# ML local enviornment

Tags: ml

ML function that will accept a boolean function and a list of values and return the last value in the list that meets the given condition or NONE if no values in the list do

my current function looks like this:

```
fun last func nil = NONE
| last func L = 
    let val f = 
        fun getlast(x) = SOME x
        | getlast(x::xs) = getlast xs
    in List.filter func L
    end;
```

Can anyone help me debug my code and also help me understand local environment in ML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overcomplicating this a bit, and it's unclear what the purposes of `f` and `getlast` could be as you're never using them (and the "definition" of `f` is a syntax error).

If you test your `getlast` outside of this function (this is usually a good idea) you'll notice that `getlast []` is `SOME []` and `getlast [1,2,3]` is `SOME [1,2,3]`; `getlast y` is `SOME y` no matter what `y` you pass to it.

Also, the result of `List.filter func L` is an `'a list`, not an `'a option`, so it's not very useful as the definition of `last`.

One way of finding such an element in the list `xs` is using explicit recursion:

- If `xs` is empty, the result is `NONE`.
- If `xs` is not empty, first see if there is a "last element" in the tail of `xs`.
  If there is, that's the answer.
  If there isn't, then

  - If `func` holds for the head of `xs`, that's your answer.
  - Otherwise, the result is `NONE`.

Translating this to ML, it might look something like this:

```
fun last _ [] = NONE
  | last f (x::xs) = case last f xs of
                         NONE => if f x then SOME x else NONE
                       | result => result
```

If you want to use `List.filter` and avoid manual recursion, then note that the last element of a list is the first element of the reverse of that list:

```
fun last f xs = case List.rev (List.filter f xs) of
                     [] => NONE
                   | y::ys => SOME y
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own environment for ML or any new project

```
$ virtualenv -p python3 env (if you have 2.7,3.5)
$ virtualenv env(only you have 3.5+)

$ source env/bin/activate
$ pip install <packagename>
```